# SQL query to show multiple counts over the last day

Tags: mysql, sql, validation

How do i formulate a sql query where i can display  the number  of  counts of success and errors and warning for the tables for  latest day . So I can create a visualization in dashboard. The ultimate goal is for  a user to know on a current day how many healthy pipelines are there and how many unhealthy pipelines are there.

i tried something like this, but i complicated it.

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) as Total, cast(cast(time as Timestamp) as date) as time,
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Success,
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Warning' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Warning,
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Error
FROM table-name
where (cast(cast(time as Timestamp) as date) in ({{ Time }}) or {{ Time }} = 'All')
GROUP BY 1, cast(cast(time as Timestamp) as date)
order by cast(cast(time as Timestamp) as date) desc
```

lets say this is the given table
[image]

Comment: Why are you casting the timestamp? Is it a varchar? If so that's very bad, and this demonstrates one of the _many_ reasons why: the cast invalidates any index you might have on the column for this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i formulate a sql query where i can display the number of counts of success and errors and warning for the tables for latest day .

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT DATE(time) as date, COUNT(*) as Total, ,
       SUM(Status = 'Success') as Success,
       SUM(Status = 'Warning') as Warning,
       SUM(Status = 'Error') as Error
FROM table-name
WHERE date(time) = (SELECT MAX(date(time)) FROM table-name)
GROUP BY 1;
```